# How to make Rust cursive's examples work on Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, rust, cross-platform, tui

[Rust cursive](https://github.com/gyscos/cursive) is a Rust TUI framework. It [states that](https://github.com/gyscos/cursive/wiki/Backends) you can switch backends and some of which are Windows supported. However, I can't make it work. When I run the following command (grabbed from [here](https://github.com/gyscos/cursive/wiki/Backends)) I got an error:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/gyscos/cursive
$ cd cursive/examples

$ cargo run -v --no-default-features --features pancurses-backend --example select
error: Package `cursive-examples v0.1.1-alpha.0 (C:\my_projects\cursive\examples)`
does not have the feature `pancurses-backend`
```

What's the correct way to run these examples on Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, the [`examples` package](https://github.com/gyscos/cursive/tree/main/examples) does not have a `pancurses-backend` feature, which if you look in [`examples/Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/gyscos/cursive/blob/main/examples/Cargo.toml#L22-L23) is correct. The `pancurses-backend` feature is actually located in the [`Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/gyscos/cursive/blob/main/cursive/Cargo.toml#L57) for `cursive`.

So to enable it, you have to do `--features cursive/pancurses-backend` instead.

While the directory is *somewhat misleadingly* called `examples`. You can't use `--example` in this case, as they're not examples in the Cargo sense. Instead you need to use `--bin`.

```sh
cargo run -v --no-default-features --features cursive/pancurses-backend --bin select
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting

```
[dependencies.cursive] 
version = "0.20.0"
default-features = false
features = ["crossterm-backend"]
```

in Cargo.toml also worked for me on Windows

then simply fire

```
cargo run
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted, setting options in Cargo.toml instead of command line.